# Migration of question

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, migration

I recently had a question of mine migrated from the English Site to the Linguistics site (link below).

The question relates to the field of Computational Linguistics which is an amalgamation of Language, Linguistics, Mathematics, and Computer Science (at the very least).

I appreciate and understand that some may feel this is a linguistic styled question, however I very specifically wanted to obtain answers from the perspective of Language.

I'm unsure what the process is here, but could  I please have the question re-instated and/or re-ask on this site?

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/33717/what-frameworks-are-there-for-computational-linguistics?noredirect=1#comment73294_33717

Comment: Isn't linguistics about the scientific study of *language*? I don't quite understand 
 your opposition, the question is not abandoned or closed  because a better home has been found.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Please also note, that I want the question answered from multiple perspectives - language, linguistics, computational linguistics, natural language programming, applied mathematics (both real and complex analysis), philosophy of language, ... and essentially any field that may be able to contribute. 

My PhD studies involved work in using Quantum Like Entanglement models for free association. This came about from an observation of a body that saw the intersection of language and quantum mechanics. Thus, multiple bodies are key to the fields development.

Comment: «*That's why I'm interested in any commentary*» The Stack Exchange model is unfavourable towards answers based on opinion, if you are looking for in-depth, profound, and  philosophical answers, you will always be disappointed. And there's no need to capitalise *language* twice,  I can still read.

Comment: "I appreciate and understand that some may feel this is a linguistic styled question, however I very specifically wanted to obtain answers from the perspective of Language." "Language" isn't an academic field. This really doesn't make much sense sorry.

Comment: @curiousdannii - then why does this SE exist? does it need to be based in a field of study for there to be a body of useful information to garner from it?

Comment: @curiousdannii - In this specific instance, do you feel there is no one person that has something of value to contribute?

Comment: @DavidGalea This site isn't about "Language", it's about English. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please do not simply ask the same question again. It's already been judged as off-topic and better suited to a different site (where comments indicate it's been reasonably well-received).

If you specifically want to ask about the English language, that ***could*** be on-topic here; but I would suggest that you wait until you have a general answer upon which to base a more specific question — and then it will probably be better to ask it on Linguistics where there is a community who could narrow down their focus.

The only way of having a migrated question re-instated is to have the recipient site send it back. That will mean that it's off-topic on that site. But — as it's also off-topic on this site — it will simply end up closed and require five votes to reopen.

The moderator who cast the vote to move your question does in fact know quite a bit about language, linguistics and computer science (and probably maths), and given that it has been well received and Linguistics.SE actually have a [computational-linguistics] tag and we don't, I suggest it's left where it is.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Leach - So, even with a re-positioning of the question to account for why I believe it's warranted to be posted here  - that is not allowed?

Comment: And is there no way to contest a judgement  made re 'off-topic'?

Comment: If you **ask a different question** which is [on-topic](/help/on-topic) then that's fine, in theory. It does need to be sufficiently different from the last one and within the on-topic list which we publish. However, I suspect that the subject matter is best dealt with elsewhere. The way to "contest a judgement" is to ask a Meta question which **specifically defends the question as on-topic on ELU.** You have to explain rigorously [in the academic sense of *rigour*] why it belongs here and what sort of answer you expect to get.

Comment: @Academic Leach - academic rigour? - you're joking surely?
Thanks for the other information. I will re-post.

Comment: Or @Andrew Leach  - What if I wanted to ask why 'Language' isn't an appropriate domain to ask questions related to Natural Language Processing and/or Computational Linguistics?

Comment: Feel free to ask on Meta. Expect downvotes. They have a "Computational Linguistics" tag; we don't. Your question does not fit our [on-topic](/help/on-topic) list. Oh, and no, I'm not joking.

Comment: My comment re 'joking' was in jest as there doesn't appear to be academic rigour on this site. Votes are not quantified, closure is based on categories with no quantification, those who close a question can vote on it being re-opened and I'm sure many more. This is very much not academic rigour. 

StacKExchange appears to operate more like 'Question Time' in politics than an Academic based process.

Comment: Given no reasons are needed  to be provided for 'down votes' - I don't take them with any seriousness. The feedback given (when given) I certainly do.

Comment: @DavidGalea You haven't been on the receiving end of a peer review that gives you no useful critique? You must be very lucky then!

Comment: @curiousdannii - I've been an editor and I've had many papers edited. Have I received invalid feedback? Yes - but then you can press further - that is the academic process... or better put, that of which I've been part of. I'm sorry you've had to suffer through poor reviews, but that's no excuse to make it the standard on SE.

Comment: @curiousdannii - What do you think can be done to improve feedback on SE?

Comment: @DavidGalea In all your contributions there has been feedback. Every post and request of yours has received several comments. This comment of mine, is  also feedback. Asking users to justify their downvote has been asked a zillion times, across the entire network. The official response has always been the same for the last 11 years. || Paraphrasing: Voting is anonymous, no one asks why someone upvotes, why is it different for a downvote? There is nothing stopping a user from posting a comment asking for clarification, suggesting improvements or explaining why a post is erroneous.

Comment: As to your reply to curiousdannii `I'm sorry you've had to suffer through poor reviews, but that's no excuse to make it the standard on SE.` I am flabbergasted that no one has picked up on that. However, I suggest that you visit the help centre: https://english.stackexchange.com/help, and the archives in meta to better understand and appreciate the culture here on EL&U, which isn't perfect by any means but it's certainly more generous than your representation of it.