# Is there any way for a user to know if there is a report on them?

Tags: discussion, support

I just had a user comment on a question I posted that there was a 'Report' on myself. He/she deleted the comment fairly quickly, but it left the question as to whether what he/she said was correct? and if so, is there any way to find out if there is a report on a given user and it's status/content?

Are reports formed on users? and what is the process associated with that?

Comment: The OP is referring to [this question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13456/migration-of-question#comment56817_13456) , in which I noted/flagged  they were being disrespectful.

Comment: I just saw the comments and flagged as unkind. To answer your question David: no, as I told you in the answer you just accepted on another of your pile of meta questions, anyone can cast a flag but only the mods can see them or act on them. You get no visibility except in the form of moderator contact if the flags pile up and they decide you need a talking to. This is the first last and only comment I will post on this topic or under this or any of your other meta questions.

Comment: @DanBron - That's not what I asked, but thank you for the information.

Comment: @Mari-LouA this question seems more rudimentary asking what sort of reports are made regarding users.

Comment: @JJJ I was attracted by Colleen's answer more than the actual OP.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd say they don't have an answer there but it appears they changed their name.

Comment: @JJJ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper/333992#comment1090769_333992

Answer (score 7):

Given the context, I believe what you mean by "report" is whether a flag has been raised on a post or comment that you wrote. The answer is no. If I have misunderstood what you are asking, please edit your question to clarify.